# Trying to filter by dynamically added property/value in object array and save to state

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I was wondering if anybody could help, I have a function that when it runs it will do a fetch and save the object array it gets to a variable, it will then loop through that object array and do another fetch and based on some data in that fetch it will add a new property/value to each object inside the array, I have that working fine, however I then want to filter the array by that new properties value and set the updated object array to state, the problem is the filter doesn't seem to be working, all I get back is the unfiltered data.

Code below, any help would be amazing.

```
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import ResultsPage from './components/ResultsPage'

const App = () => {

    const [results, setResults] = useState([])
    const searchedRef = useRef()

    useEffect(() => {
       console.log(results)
    }, [results])

    const handleSearch = async () => {
        let searched = searchedRef.current.value
        let res = await fetch(`someAPI/${searched}`)
        let data = await res.json()
        searchResults = data


        res = null
        data = null

        searchResults.map(async (element) => {
            res = await fetch(`someAPI/${element}`)
            data = await res.json()
            element.name = data.name;
        });

        searchResults = searchResults.filter(element => element.name !== null);

        setResults(searchResults)
    }

    return (
        <>
            <input type="text" ref={searchedRef} onKeyDown={handleSearch}/>
            <ResultsPage results={results} />
        </>
    )

}

export default App
```

Comment: this code is running asynchronously. `setResults` has executed before `searchResults` is updated with the filter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The map will not wait for each fetch to be done.

Async functions evaluate to Promises, so the mapping will evaluate to an array of Promises.

You need to use `Promise.all` to wait on an array of Promises.

```
await Promise.all(searchResults.map(/* ... */))
```

Example [here](https://flaviocopes.com/javascript-async-await-array-map/).